# php: Проблема с запуском .exe файла, который находится на сервере

Tags: php, exe, site

Я делаю форму на сайте , там вводятся всякие данные, затем я нажимаю кнопку и все что было введено на формах записывается в файл(здесь проблем нет), но следующим действием я хочу запустить .exe файл проекта от delphi( по сути должна запуститься консоль и что то посчитаться и выведать в другой файл, Но ничего подобного не происходит. Если кто то сталкивался с данной проблемой поделитесь ее решением .
Ниже приведу то, что я уже испробовал, но результата не дало.

1)

```
pclose(popen("start C:\Denver\home\localhost\mySite\www\CONf2016M\PROGNOS\progn64.exe "));
```

2)

```
exec('start\'C:\\Denver\\home\\localhost\\mySite\\www\\CONf2016M\\PROGNOS\\progn64.exe\'  '); (здесь вообще говорит, что не найден данный файл)
```

3)

```
$cmd = "start C:\Denver\home\localhost\mySite\www\CONf2016M\PROGNOS\progn64.exe -name:name "; 
pclose(popen($cmd,'w'));
```

Действия происходящие при выполнения данного кода, примерно одинаковые быстро всплывает консоль и гаснет, но выполнение программы не осуществляется .

Comment: Ну вы делаете `popen` а потом сразу `pclose`,  экранировать бекслеши - не экранируете, странно что вообще работает.  Учтите, что все функции по выполнению приложений как правило заблокированы на настоящих веб-серверах, дабы злоумушленник, получивший доступ к PHP коду не получил доступ к серверу в целом.

Comment: В случае exec перед start как будто пробела не хватает... Ну да ладно. Это не ответ, просто совет: выясните, где у вас лежат логи PHP, и что пишется в этих логах. Если Denwer, то это в внутри него. В 90% случаев записи в этих логах дадут вам подробный ответ, почему так происходит. В оставшихся 10% я бы рекомендовал взять весь-весь вывод запускаемого файла и посмотреть также и в него. Может быть он там как раз пишет, что ему не хватает для счастья.

Comment: А вообще, если вам нужно что-то сделать обязательно в приложении Delphi, приняв данные от скрипта php, я бы рекомендовал не вызывать приложение, а передать ему данные через сокет. Ну то есть в Delphi встать на TCPSocket localhost:<port>, а в PHP просто подключиться на localhost:<port> и послать полученные данные. Результаты вычислений можно получить так же. Запускать что-то из PHP - плохая идея. Очень.

Comment: @wirtwelt спасибо за совет , а если я пойти путем, который вы предложили через сокет , я могу к примеру создать проект на delphi,  с помощью которого я установлю сокет и запущу .exe файл?

Comment: Нет, не совсем так. Ваш проект на Delphi будет запущен постоянно, и встанет на порт, например на localhost:40103 (также, как сервер HTTP или SSH, чтоб было понятнее). И будет этот порт слушать, без всякого файла. А скрипт PHP, когда ему нужно будет что-то посчитать, подключится по сети на порт localhost:40103 и пошлет туда текст/данные с задачей. Приложение Delphi примет данные, посчитает и вернет ответ скрипту. Дело в том, что запускать что-то из скрипта - это очень плохая идея в плане безопасности. Для взаимодействия приложений обычно используют механизмы безопасной передачи данных.